# Why do I keep getting IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x

[This is my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX4NM.png)

Why do I have keep getting index error whenever I provided less than 3 in my command line argument

[This is the sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD0um.png)

Comment: When you're providing less than 3 arguments in your command line, you're still trying to access `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` even though they aren't there.

Comment: 1) You can add your source code directly to the question instead of an image. 2) With `python3 fruits.py apple`, you only pass 1 argument but you try to get 2nd and 3rd. If you use `python3 fruits.py apple arg2 arg3`, it will not raise an error.

Comment: Oww, okay I get it, how do i fix it thou??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much better to put the actual code instead of an image by the way.

You are trying to get index 2 (3rd item in the list) of a list that only has 2 items in it when you do `second_arg = sys.argv[2]`. Since the list is not that long, that is why it is throwing an error.

You may want to do your assignments after your if statement. That way you'll know that you can index that far.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are checking after you have assigned the values.

Try implementing an If else statement.

if (has 3 arguments):

```
assign values
```

else:

```
print('Missing/Many Arguments')
```